# Removing index.php using .htaccess not working on codeigniter hostgator

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

Basically I want to remove index.php in my url.

I think my .htaccess is not working on Hostgator and I've already searched my problem on these .htaccess, codeigniter and hostgator.

This is my folder structure in hostgator

> /cgi-bin 
>  /httpdocs 
>       |---/application 
>       |---/system 
>       |---.htaccess 
>       |---index.php

My `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

My `config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'www.example.com'; // this is only an example because our website is confidential
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

> **Edit:** Sorry for being idiot. I contacted the Hostgator after I posted this question and try the answers below. They say that I'm
>   running on `Windows server` not `Apache server` so my `.htaccess` will
>   not work so I need to convert it to `web.config`. Sorry for those
>   wasted time to answer this question. Thank you
>
> **Edit:** I mark @Deep Parekh's answer as correct as @David said that it worked properly

Comment: do you changed config.php ?

Comment: @DeepParekh Yes sir I've already changed the config.php

Comment: @ Thanks Deep parekh i solved my issue using your code.... @Kapitan Awesome accept someone's answer so user can find solution.

Comment: @David I updated my post and mark Deep Parekh's answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally i use this htaccess on Hostgator:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure you changed your config.php file:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

Comment: still `404 - File or directory not found.`

Comment: check your routes.php file that you define your default controller and try to debug by echo something....

Comment: Thanks for helping sir. I'm idiot that I posted this question first before contacting the Hostgator.

Comment: @ Thanks Deep parekh i solved my issue using your code.... @Kapitan Awesome accept someone's answer so user can find solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible to use the htaccess. 
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/apache-htaccess/how-to-edit-your-htaccess-file

Maybe try these htaccess. It works at my local project.

```
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|\.swf|forums|images|css|downloads|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*) ./index.php [L]
```

Comment: still `404 - File or directory not found.`

Comment: Do you have a webserver or a webspace?

Comment: Try the new code in my answer. Maybe this will work for you.

Comment: Ok i'll give my feedback later

Comment: Thanks for helping sir. I'm idiot that I posted this question first before contacting the Hostgator.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess will look :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]



# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

In codeiginator config:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

If htaccess is not working then

1. Configure Apache mod_rewrite

   a2enmod rewrite
2. Add the following code to /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

   AllowOverride All

Comment: Thanks for helping sir. I'm idiot that I posted this question first before contacting the Hostgator.

Answer (score 0):

In `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

In .htacess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule
```

Comment: still `404 - File or directory not found.`

Comment: did you remove base url??

Comment: yes I removed it and test the .htaccess code you posted but still file not found

Comment: did you add any new controllers in your project??

Comment: Thanks for helping sir. I'm idiot that I posted this question first before contacting the Hostgator.

Answer (score 0):

This is works for me:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```